# How to find all matches of text between two fixed tokens with PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for the string (or strings - there might be many occurrences), between the following:

`<!--##` and `##-->`

Example: from the input `<!--##HELLO##-->` I need to match `HELLO`.

What would be the regex?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Edit: thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to study regular expressions. You're not using the right terminology and this regular expression that you are looking for is elementary.

Comment: Indeed, I've never or almost never worked with regex.  And regex match wasn't the proper way to say it, I guess "regular expression" would be it ?

Comment: You can either say "what would be the regex" or "what would be the regex pattern". The match in this case is `HELLO`. I guess you could also say "what regex would I need for this match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex

```
<!--##(.*?)##-->
```

Will store the text in the first group. Be sure to set the option that lets the . match newline (/s below)

For php preg this becomes

```
if (preg_match('/<!--##(.*?)##-->/s', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  What would it be if there are many occurrences of the pattern in the string ?

Comment: It was more than I was looking for and also for the record I used pre_match_all which populated the array $regs with all the matches.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alex the question mark in the (.*?) makes the regex match *lazy* wich will match the smallest occurrence of <!-- text -->. If the question marks was left out (regex becomes *greedy*) it would not have worked for many occurrences but it would have found the longest match.

Answer (score 5):

```
(?<=<!--##).*?(?=##-->)
```

Lookaround is the only way to match only the `HELLO`. You can also match the entire `<!--##HELLO##-->` and extract captured groups as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Assuming he wants to use it for some kind of variable replacement using lookahead/behind conditions might not be the best idea though.

Comment: He said he's looking for `HELLO`, not `<!--##HELLO##-->`

Comment: I'm not really sure why the lookbehinds/aheads are necessary except for optimizing?  And that makes it premature optimization since it's more esoteric.

Comment: @djechlin: They aren't for optimization. They are for matching only the text asked for.

Comment: @KendallFrey I get a NULL array and a warning message with your regex : Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '.' ... is this normal ?

Comment: @Alex: I don't think so. Did you properly enclose the regex in slashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
/<!--##(.*?)##-->/
```

Basically this is an alternative way to do this to other provided answer because I think it's simpler to use matching groups to fish out your text than to use look ahead/behind to only match what you're looking for.  Tomato, Tom-ah-to.

Comment: True, but they match `<!--##HELLO##-->`. Perhaps you need to flesh it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `preg_match_all`, and an iterator that gives you each match:

```
$match_list = array();
if( preg_match_all('/<!--##(.*?)##-->/s', $subject, $regs) ) {
    $match_list = $regs[1];
} else {
    echo "Warning: No matches found in: " . $subject;
}

foreach($match_list as $i=>$v) {
    echo "Match: " . $i . " : " . $v . "\n";
}
```